# Labels not appear or wrapping after adding function Angular D3

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I added a basic wrapping function that I got from [here](https://bl.ocks.org/guypursey/f47d8cd11a8ff24854305505dbbd8c07). But when I load the chart, the labels don't wrap. I've done some debugging and it doesn't appear as though the information coming into the wrap function is correct. It seems empty.

[image]

Here is where I call the function:

```
//add the x-axis
    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x0))
      .select(".domain").remove()
      .selectAll(".tick text")
      //use wrap function to wrap long lines in labels
      .call(this.wrap, x0.bandwidth());
```

Here is the wrap function:

```
wrap(text, width) {
    text.each(function () {
      var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
      while (word = words.pop()) {
        line.push(word);
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
          line.pop();
          tspan.text(line.join(" "));
          line = [word];
          tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

It probably has something to do with how finicky Angular is with D3, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the selectAll to be a little more explicit did the trick. Not sure why it wasn't getting the correct components with the previous code.

```
//add the x-axis
    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x0))
      .select(".domain").remove()
      
    g.selectAll(".tick text")
      //use wrap function to wrap long lines in labels
      .call(this.wrap, x0.bandwidth());
```